# LinearGradientBrush not working on Android in Landscape View

Tags: maui, lineargradientbrush

In my .NET MAUI App I use a LinearGradientBrush on top of a BackgroundImage like this:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *">

    <!-- BackgroundImage and LinearGradient -->
    <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage" Grid.Row="0" Source="radiant_gradient.png" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
    <ScrollView Grid.Row="0">
        <ScrollView.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ScrollView.Background>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView x:Name="ScrollView" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" BackgroundColor="Transparent" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    
    </ScrollView
    
</Grid>
```

In Code-Behind there is an adaption of the Size of the BackgroundImage so that it looks good when in Portrait and Landscape View:

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    if (height > 0)
    {
        BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7;
    }
}
```

Now, on **iOS** it all looks good and smooth:

**Portrait-View:**

[image]

**Landscape-View:**

[image]

Unfortunately, on **Android** only the **Portrait-View** looks good and **Landscape-View** looks like there is no LinearGradient calculated:

**Portrait-View:**

[image]

**Landscape-View:**

On this Screenshot you see a hard edge and it is not blurred out/fade out like on iOS

[image]

I also tried with an inner Grid instead of the ScrollView for the LinearGradientBrush, but without effect.

Is there anything I can do here to make Android look the same as iOS in Landscape-View? The effect on iOS is what it should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new project to test your code on the Android. And I found:

1. If I remove the `BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7;` in the code behind. The **LinearGradientBrush** will work in Landscape-View. But the image will look strange.
2. If I keep the `BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7;` in the code behind and run the project in Landscape-View at first. The **LinearGradientBrush** will also work.

But if I keep the `BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7;` in the code behind and run it Portrait-View at first. After I change the device to Landscape-View, the imageview seems to be cut off by `BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7;`.

It seems a new issue for the android. You can post a new issue on the github. And you can try to set the `BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7;` only for Portrait-View for the android. Such as:

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
#if IOS
    if (height > 0)
    {
        BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7;
    }
#endif
#if ANDROID 
    if (height > width)
    {
        BackgroundImage.HeightRequest = height * 0.7;
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Do you know where on GitHub I could write this as a Bug? This is Android for .NET MAUI, isn't it or is this an Android only problem? I think what you proposed does leave the Background Image in it's original state when in Landscape orientation and well, I think this does look good. Thank you very much for your help. I am really surprised by how many differences and Bug there are in .NET MAUI. When I think back to Java which is a similar concept for me (with a VM), no matter if you worked on different Operating Systems everything looked the same. Don't know how many differences I had so far

Comment: You can [post the issue here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues). @OXO

Comment: Thanks - link is https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16392